# How to migrate my app.yaml to 2.7?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml

I'm migrating my gae app to python 2.7. This is my new app.yaml:

```
application: webfaze
version: main
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce/main.application

- url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*
  expiration: "1d"

- url: .*
  script: main.application

- url: /task/.*
  script: main.application
  login: admin
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error parsing yaml file:
Invalid object:
threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: mapreduce/main.application
  in "webfaze/app.yaml", line 22, column 1
```

Can you tell me how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py&q=%22threadsafe%20cannot%20be%20enabled%20with%20CGI%20handler%22%20package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=893), it looks that you need to define your handlers' path without any slash:

```
   if (handler.script and (handler.script.endswith('.py') or 
       '/' in handler.script)):
       raise appinfo_errors.ThreadsafeWithCgiHandler(
                    'threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: %s' %
                    handler.script)
```

Move `application.py` to the root of your project and modify the handler's path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it's true I could just omit the mapreduce part since I'm not using it at the moment. Now update passed the syntax check and I'm curious to see what has happened now that I just ran `set_default_version`

Comment: Or name it `mapreduce.main.application`.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Johnson for the complete solution. I could migrate the entire app to python 2.7 with little effort :-)

Comment: I still had trouble with naming `mapreduce.main.application` after hunting on the internet, I found script: `google.appengine.ext.mapreduce.main.APP` from: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/ZzW4hhqc7hI

Answer (score 7):

**Change:**

```
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce/main.application
```

**To:**

```
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce.main.application
```

You may also need to add an **__init__.py** to the 'mapreduce' folder if one doesn't exist there already. That will make the python interpret the folder as a module.

Comment: I tried latest version and it seems it changed from application to APP

Comment: @wonglik By 'latest version' which version would that be. I'm running v.1.7.0 of the SDK and changing 'application' to 'app' throws a 500 (Server) error.

Comment: Sorry. I meant latest version of MapReduce Bundle - 1.6.2 taken from here https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: @wonglik Maybe that'll change to match the other versions once it's brought up-to-date. According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview the MapReduce Bundle is still considered experimental.

Comment: I found that you also have to make a similar change to mapreduce/include.yaml