# Mapreduce no longer works after 2.7 conversion

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, mapreduce, python-2.7

After converting our app to Python 2.7, configuring for multithreading, and referencing mapreduce in app.yaml like this...

```
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce.main.app
  #script: google.appengine.ext.mapreduce.main.app
  login: admin
```

and invoking mapreduce like this...

```
  control.start_map(
      "FNFR",
      "fnfr.fnfrHandler",
      "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
      {"blob_keys": blobKey},
      shard_count=32,
      mapreduce_parameters={'done_callback': '/fnfrdone','blobKey': blobKey, 'userID':thisUserID})
```

we get the following stack trace...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 189, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 241, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'mapreduce.main' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~xxxxxxonline/2.361692533819432574/mapreduce/main.pyc'> has no attribute app
```

I found one SO reference ( [How to migrate my app.yaml to 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945889/how-to-migrate-my-app-yaml-to-2-7) ) but as you can see from my yaml, I think I've tried all combinations to try to get it to resolve.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me, but I'm still on a pretty old version of the SDK, I don't know if they fixed this:

```
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce.main.APP
  login: admin
```

Comment: I think that's gotten me further, thank you. The next issue -- don't know if it's related -- but now it looks like the mapreduce's calls to worker_callback are failing with "TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)".  I'm wondering now if I've somehow got the wrong version of mapreduce.

Comment: IMPORTANT: Okay, I've got it all working. In addition to @dragonx's solution, I also had to download and pull in the latest MapReduce source and change the line in mapreduce/include.yaml to also look like this "script: mapreduce.main.APP".  And in both places the APP in all caps is required.  Final note, i saw a post that said if you're using the pipeline part of mapreduce (not just the mapper), at this time you need a patch. Basically, I think we're using a version of mapreduce that hasn't been updated for 2.7 multithreading yet.

Comment: Too long ago now, but it wasn't too hard to figure out by debugging through the SDK code.